# Plot a fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, graphing-functions

I'm not a mathematician but I hope my question is easily answered.

I'm trying to learn about graphing equations in a computer application (I'm a programmer).

From [this link](http://dev.oberonplace.com/products/securidesign/function.htm) a fourier series is described as

$F(t) = C + A_1\cos(\omega t) + B_1\sin(\omega t) + A_2\cos(2 \omega t) + B_2\sin(2 \omega t) + A_3\cos(3 \omega t) + B_3\sin(3 \omega t) + ... + A_n\cos(n \omega t) + B_n\sin(n \omega t)$

I'm not clear what the $C$ symbol represents, nor the omega symbol ($\omega$).

Can someone explain these to me or point me to some resources to study?  As I alluded to earlier, my mathematical background is not great.

Comment: $C$ is a constant. This site might be helpful: http://www.sosmath.com/fourier/fourier2/fourier2.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $F(t)$ is periodic with period $T=2\pi/\omega$. $C$ is the average value of $F(t)$, and $\omega$ is the fundamental frequency of $F(t)$ in radians, i.e. $\omega=2\pi /T$, where $1/T$ is the fundamental frequency in Hz. So the function $F(t)$ is represented by its average plus sinusoids with frequencies at integer multiples of the fundamental frequency.